# Keeping towns alive

Tags: illyriad

With respect to towns of abandoned players: these will vanish after 90 days unless sieges are put around them, and the practice of putting siege encampment around towns to stop them vanishing is called placeholder sieges.

Do placeholder sieges keep them alive from when the encampment is formed or from then the siege army is sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From GC, 22nd Feb 2017:

> > [08:17]Hobblez: it should be once the incoming is sent, you can also just send diplo missions to keep an account active
> >
> > [08:18]Hobblez:  As long as they have another player actively trying to take something from the account it won't delete
> >
> > [08:18]Mistery:  as per my answer from earlier - [08:14]Mistery:  abandoned towns will stay in place as long as there are hostile
> >     actions taken against it
> >
> > [08:19]Alti:  Do scounts count as hostile?
> >
> > [08:19]Kodabear:  yes
> >
> > [08:19]Kodabear:  no
> >
> > [08:19]Kodabear:  no
> >
> > [08:20]Kodabear:  the game doesnt count them as hostile
> >
> > [08:20]Kodabear:  players on the other hand due
> >
> > [08:20]Alti:  So they won't keep a town around?
> >
> > [08:20]Kodabear:  yes?
> >
> > [08:20]Kodabear:  ish
> >
> > [08:21]Hobblez:  from what I've heard any diplo or military action against a player will keep the account "active" aka not delete it
> >
> > [08:21]Kodabear:  when it comes to terms of runes they arent counted as hostile